# R - running into duplication error when merging

Tags: r, join, merge

I have a data set that tells me a customer email, customer number, and whether or not they are an admin.  We need to provide the customer's admin's email on the same record and we can derive that from the data from seeing that wherever a record has a customer number that is equal to an admin record's number, put the admin's email in that line.  Also, the 'second admin' should have his own email appear in the 'admin email' field rather than the 'first admin' for that customer.

I've accomplished this by subsetting the admins into a new dataframe and then merging the admin data set and the original data set on Customer number.  THE ISSUE is when a customer has 2 admins because the join causes for duplicate records.  Is there any way around this like 'if 2 admins listed for 1 customer, use the 1st admin email'?

```
##sample Data
    df <- data.frame(Email = c("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com","test5@gmail.com","test6@gmail.com", "test7@gmail.com"),
                     Admin = c("Y", "N", "N","Y","N", "Y", "N"),
                     CustNum = c("1111","1111","1111","2222","2222","2222", "2222"))

##My solution
admins <- subset(df, df$Admin == "Y")
output <- merge(df, admins, by = "CustNum", all.x = TRUE)
colnames(output)[colnames(output)=="Email.y"] <- "Admin_Email"


    expected <- data.frame(Email = c("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com","test5@gmail.com","test6@gmail.com", "test7@gmail.com"),
                           Admin = c("Y", "N", "N","Y","N", "Y", "N"),
                           CustNum = c("1111","1111","1111","2222","2222","2222", "2222"),
                     Adminemail = c("test1@gmail.com","test1@gmail.com","test1@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com","test6@gmail.com", "test4@gmail.com"))
```

Comment: So you want to keep the x intact ?

Comment: Or you just want to add the column ''Admin_email ?

Comment: sorry @NicoCoallier I am new to the site and overlooked your comments (went straight to the Answers :) .. I want to keep x intact and add the column 'admin email' the end result is the same (correct) number of users with the corresponding admin email assigned.  Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer satisfied you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution without using loop, but it works, try this.

```
## sample Data
df <- data.frame(Email = c("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com","test5@gmail.com","test6@gmail.com", "test7@gmail.com"),
             Admin = c("Y", "N", "N","Y","N", "Y", "N"),
             CustNum = c("1111","1111","1111","2222","2222","2222", "2222"))

## My solution
library(dplyr)
admins <- df %>% filter(Admin == 'Y') %>% 
    select(Email, Admin, CustNum) %>% 
    mutate(AdminEmail = Email)
# find the first match for each unique CustNum
ind = sapply(unique(admins$CustNum), function(x) which(admins$CustNum == x)[1])
first_match = admins[ind, ]
# merge data
output = full_join(df, admins, by = c('Email', 'CustNum', 'Admin'))
# fill in NAs
for (i in 1:nrow(output)) {
    if (is.na(output$AdminEmail[i])) {
        output$AdminEmail[i] = first_match$AdminEmail[which(first_match$CustNum == output$CustNum[i])]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is with a for loops. But there is a way with data.table but I can figure it out ...

***WORKING SOLUTION*** but not optimal

```
df$Adminemail = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

    ### If the admin is himself then :
    if(df$Admin[i] == "Y"){
    df$Adminemail[i] = as.character(df$Email[i])
    }

    ### Otherwise it fill up with the first admin-email found
    else{
    sub <- df[df$CustNum == df$CustNum[i],]
    df$Adminemail[i] <- as.character(sub[sub$Admin=="Y",]$Email[1])
    }
    }
```

If your dataset is large, the for loops might give you some problem. However if you could create a unique ID. I am pretty sure data.table as some better and more optimal solutions.

***NOT WORKING SOLUTION*** but possibly better avenue

```
  df$Unique <- paste(df$Email,df$CustNum,sep="_")


  library(data.table)
  setDT(df) 
  setDT(admins)

  # inner join - use `nomatch` argument
  admins[df, nomatch=0L, on = "Unique"]
```

I found this piece of code at this [post](https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-12-11/Solve-common-R-problems-efficiently-with-data.table.html)